# Bootstrap card: set proper card-block height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling getting this html layout to work:

```
<div class="card" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="card-header">Title</div>
    <div class="card-block>
        <chart class="row" style="height: 100%"></chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem here is that, although the card has the desired height, the height of the `<chart>` element is ignored because its parent (`<div class="card-block">`) has not an explicit height.

How should I modify this snippet in order to have the `<chart>` element fill the whole card apart from the portion needed for the card-header?

EDIT: Here is the whole layout:

```
<section class="row equal my-md-3" style="height: 100%">
    <div id="left-col" class="col-md-4 pr-md-2">...</div>
    <div id="right-col" class="col-md-8 pl-md-2" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
        <featured-graphs-component style="flex-grow: 1; height: 100%;"></featured-graphs-component>
        <period-table-component class="mt-md-3" style="display: inline-block;"></period-table-component>
    </div>
</section>
```

The `<featured-graphs-component>` is the card described above.

EDIT2: JsFiddle to reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/zmcode/uk97kfLm/7/

Comment: This is version 4

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is now flexbox, and the Card is flex:direction column by default. So, the card-block should "grow", while the header will not. http://www.codeply.com/go/r9SJE984O8 I'm not able to repro the issue.

Comment: The problem is not the card-block itself but the ```<chart>``` element height. I would like it to fill the card-block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex layout to get what you want:

- make `.card`'s `display` as `flex`, and its `flex-direction` as `column`.
- make `.card-block`'s `flex` as `1`

That's it. The `chart` will flexibly occupy all space left.

The code would be:

```
<div class="card" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="card-header">Title</div>
    <div class="card-block>
        <chart class="row" style="height: 100%"></chart>
    </div>
</div>

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.card-block {
  flex: 1;
}
```

A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/23vzh95L/) has been made, please check.

Comment: This messes up once again the whole card height when I try it in the layout described in the edit. :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from the `.card-block`, and make the chart `display:flex` using (.d-flex)..

```
    <section class="row my-md-3">
        <div id="left-col" class="col-md-4 pr-md-2">...</div>
        <div id="right-col" class="col-md-8 pl-md-2">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Title</div>
                <div class="card-block bg-faded p-0">
                    <chart class="bg-info d-flex">
                        chart
                        <br><br>
                        <br><br>
                        <br><br>
                    </chart>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/r9SJE984O8

---

***EDIT*** - Based on the updated code added. CSS `height:100%` only works if the containing element has a defined height. Just add a height to: `#chart-card-container`. Also, `h-100` sets `height: 100%` in Bootstrap 4.

http://www.codeply.com/go/6Yal88nBaT

Comment: Tried this one but the chart height is still not the same as its parent.

Comment: Then can you create a fiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Still not working... I am opening a new question with a properly set up jsfiddle because I think I do not explained the problem as I should in this one.

Comment: Then please delete this question