# Set height of content in a Bootstrap Card so that it fills the whole card block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling with the layout defined here: https://jsfiddle.net/zmcode/uk97kfLm/20/.

The problem is that the red `div` inside the card on the right should fill the whole card block.

Can someone help me in understanding how I should modify this layout in order to make the `#right-card-content` fill the whole right card block?

**EDIT** the solution proposed by @MateusFelipe actually works on Firefox. Unfortunately I need it to work on Chrome (v57) too.

Comment: The red div doesn't show because it has no content.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify this point.

Comment: Do you really want that div to expand to fill or just the entire background of the card content to be red?

Comment: I need the div to expand to fill.

Comment: But what purpose does that serve?

Comment: In the actual layout that div contains a chart that should fill the whole card block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [previously explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408920/bootstrap-card-set-proper-card-block-height) that `h-100` is height: 100%, and this only works when the container has a defined height.

https://jsfiddle.net/1vgewck9/2/

```
<div class="row equal h-100">
  <div id="left-col" class="col-md-4 pr-md-2">
    <div class="card">
      Left Card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right-col" class="col-md-8 pl-md-2">
    <div id="right-card-container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Right Card</div>
        <div class="card-block h-100">
          <div id="right-card-content" class="row">.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-bottom-element" class="mt-md-3">
      Right Bottom Element
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works in the fiddle I provided so I am marking it as correct, although and it does not work in my actual layout. Also, setting up the card-block div to 100% should not make it the same height of its parent, i.e. the card div, thus ignoring the height of the header?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/uk97kfLm/21/) may solve your problem.

I've set the div's `width` to `100%`, removed the `row` class from it, and removed the padding of parent (`card-block`) with `p-0`.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

div.card {
  height: 100%;
}

#left-col {
  height: 100%;
}

#right-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#right-card-container {
  flex: 1;
}

#right-card-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

#right-bottom-element {
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row equal h-100">
  <div id="left-col" class="col-md-4 pr-md-2">
    <div class="card">
      Left Card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right-col" class="col-md-8 pl-md-2">
    <div id="right-card-container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Right Card</div>
        <div class="card-block p-0">
          <div id="right-card-content"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-bottom-element" class="mt-md-3">
      Right Bottom Element
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like the ```div``` is not filling the card yet. Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: It's working here. Isn't this your intended behaviour? http://imageshack.com/a/img924/2394/CEGMqy.png

Comment: In the link you posted the right card it's still empty... I tried what you suggested but I cannot achieve the result in your screenshot.

Comment: What I did was to hack your code, I don't made my own. What browser are you using? Maybe it's not showing because of what @DavidG said before.

Comment: Wow ok I guess the problem is the browser... I was on Chrome and it was not working, now I switched to Firefox and your solution it's working. I have no idea why.

Comment: If my answer is the appropriated for your question, please, mark it.

Comment: The problem is I need it to work on Chrome actually.